# C++ optimal way of bring the ones to the front of an array of zeros and ones

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to write the fast and coolest solution to the problem of bringing all the ones to the front of an array of zeros and ones.

I wrote this:

```
void zeros_to_front(char * c, int n)
{
   char * lastPtr(c);
   for (char * thisCharPtr(c), * endCharPtr(c+n+1); thisCharPtr != endCharPtr; ++thisCharPtr)
   {
      if (*thisCharPtr == '1')
      {
         *lastPtr = '1';
         *thisCharPtr = '0';
          ++lastPtr;
      }
   }
}

int main()
{

   char thisArray[] = {'0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1'};
   int len = sizeof(thisArray)/sizeof(char);
   zeros_to_front(thisArray, len);
   for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      std::cout << thisArray[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

A few questions:

- is there a way to simplify

  ```
  *lastIdxPtr = '1';
   ++lastIdxPtr;
  ```

  into 1 line?
- Is there an algorithm that works faster on average?

Comment: An example would be better. Count number of 1's and 0's. Run loop to copy all 1's the count number of times and zero. I don't understand purpose of bringing all 1's to front.

Comment: Have you tried `qsort`?

Comment: That takes 2 passes through the loop. Seems like the people giving programming interviews today always want a solution with 1 pass, regardless of efficiency.

Comment: You can write `*lastIdxPtr++ = '1';` to combine those 2 lines.  And there's no algorithm that works faster than linear time, because you need that amount of time to scan the entire array.

Comment: You need to swap your assignments - if the first element is 1 it will be set to 0 (because `lastPtr` and `thisCharPtr` are equal).

Comment: How bout having a pointer to the first element and a pointer to the last element; move the first one forward till you hit a `0` and the last one backwards until you hit a `1`. If they went past each other stop, otherwise swap and continue

Comment: You have a bug. The `endCharPtr` should be initialized to `c+n` to be a correct one-past-the-end iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem. I shall start with very simple one.

**Solution1:**
count the number of ones in array and fill the front elements of array with those many ones and rest of the array with zeroes. Following code does that-

```
void zero_to_front(char* c, int n)
{ 
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(c[i] == 1) count++;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if(i<count) c[i]=1;
        else c[i] = 0

}
```

Time complexity is: **O(n)**

**Solution2:** Each time you find 0 in array look for 1 in following positions in array and swap it. Following code does that.

```
void zero_to_front(int*c, int n){
    int one_pos = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (c[i] == 0) {

            if(one_pos == -1)
                one_pos = i+1;
            //Find the position of first one
            while (one_pos < n && c[one_pos] != 1 )
                one_pos++;
            //swap(c[i], c[one_pos]);
            int temp = c[i];
            c[i] = c[one_pos];
            c[one_pos] = temp;
        }

    }
}
```

Time complexity is: **O(n)**

**Solution3:**
             Sort the array in reverse order. 
Time complexity is: **O(nlogn)**

Comment: Solution2 is the best solution as it requires only one pass of array

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to do this is the two pass counting approach. Why? Because it eliminates the need for a condition in the inner loop, which is expensive. Here is the code:

```
void zerosToFront(char* c, size_t n) {
    size_t oneCount = 0, i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) oneCount += c[i];
    for(i = 0; i < n - oneCount; i++) c[i] = 0;
    for(     ; i < n; i++) c[i] = 1;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is true, but it would be better to back up your claim with some data

Answer (score 3):

This version takes the same form as cmasters' but *might* be faster depending on your standard library implementation. I know Visual C++ will turn each of these `std::fill` calls into a `memset()`.

```
void zero_to_front(char* c, int n)
{
    size_t ones = std::count(c, c + n, '1');
    std::fill(c, c + ones, '1');
    std::fill(c + ones, c + n, '0');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `count` branch internally?  I think the whole pointwas to eliminate that branch

Comment: @NiklasB.: Yes it does, I suppose `std::accumulate` might make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will require 1 pass in the array and space O(n).
  The final result is stored in array result

```
 void cal(int *data , int* result , int n) {
      int index = n - 1;
      for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
         if(data[i] == 1){
             result[index--] = 1;
         } 
      } 
  }
```